# Spring 3 @Scheduled annotation : 2processes using the same service

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a problem with Spring's `@Scheduled` annotation.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is this :

```
class service1 {
   @Scheduled(fixedDelay=120000) //120 seconds
   public void processSomething() {
      //something that processes very quick - a few seconds
      beanX.processSomething();
      ...
   }
}

class service2 {
   @Scheduled(cron="0 0 10 * * ?")
   public void processSomething() {
      //something that processes very slowly - a few hours
      beanX.processSomething();
      ...
   }
}
```

The idea in the above is that two different scheduled processes are invoking the same spring bean.

The problem I have is this :
Once the `service2` is triggered, `service1` stops getting triggered at all.

Comment: This is not by design. There's a bug in your code somewhere, but it's impossible to tell from what you've given us.

Comment: I'm sure it's not by design; I'm sure the problem is on my side. The question was more like "what can usually cause this". Please let me know what other details you would like to see in order to be able to help.

Comment: What's the version of Spring 3?  There have been a few `@Scheduled` bugs fixed.

Comment: version is 3.0.6.RELEASE. I'm aware of a few bugs, but couldn't find anything related to my problem. Also, this problem seems to appear because I'm invoking the same bean in the scheduled method, so it seems related to that. What baffles me is that the scheduler stops invoking the methods altogether rather than just (maybe) waiting for a lock or something.

Comment: Sorry guys, this is not an issue anymore. It was my own stupidity actually.
The issue was that Spring was having a very small thread pool, and I was exceeding that one by running a bunch of other threads in the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, this is not an issue anymore. It was my own stupidity actually. The issue was that Spring was having a very small thread pool, and I was exceeding that one by running a bunch of other threads in the same time.